# Sed + regex is not matching and replacing occurence with \d

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I am trying to remove the numbers at the start of the line with the following command:

```
sed -i 's/^\d*\t//' sea_news_2020_corpus.txt
```

The line looks as follows:

```
809940  The sea will be moderate in the Arabian Gulf and slight to moderate in Oman.
```

Why does this not work? Tried it for a long time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sed does not understand \d for a number. For that use [0-9] or more correctly [[:digit:]]

```
 sed -i 's/^[0-9]*\t//' yourfile
```

EDIT:

- \t is not universally understood by sed. POSIX does not mandate it. So use a shell variable for that or slip in an escaped TAB using a construct inspired from ksh $'\t'
- in place edits -i on Mac needs an argument following it , though GNU is forgiving here. Note that -i is not  mandated by Posix.

```
sed -i"" -e $'s/^[[:digit:]]*\t//' input_file
```

---

```
TAB=$(echo x | tr x '\011')
# or $(printf '\t')
sed -i"" -e "s/^[[:digit:]]*$TAB//" input _file
```

Comment: You are very right on all three. I thought that the OP is  using GNU sed because of the lone -i so => \t will be understood. But I shall add your observations to make the post future complete. Thanks.